# Spring annotation transaction mangement

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, annotations

I have a Spring & Hibernate web application in which I would to connect to two databases.

In the `web.xml` I have configured the path of the application context files as following

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath:config/*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

where I have three files under the config directory

- 1- primary-hibernateContext.xml
- 2- secondary-hibernateContext.xml
- 3- root-context.xml

In the first file I have configured the primary data source, session factory, and transaction manager(primary_manager)

I did the same in the second file

In the third file I have configured the component scan, and transaction annotation configuration as following

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!-- Enable Spring annotation configuration -->
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- Scan the application for all possible Services & autowire -->
<context:component-scan base-package="net.mr2.*.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.mr2.*.dao" />
```

I have a servlet context xml file in which I have configured the dispatcher servlet as following

```
<annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.mr2.*.web" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

The service class is annotated `@service` & `@Transactional(value="secondary_transactionManager", readOnly=true, rollbackFor=Exception.class)`.

I have a single controller in which the service is autowired.

From the controller I call three methods in the service class (`save1()`, `save2()`, `save3()`). and I throw exception in the third method and I assume that the third method should rollback but this does not happen.

I have opened the mysql logs and checked the three saving statements and I found that the statements are not executed in a transaction. I realized that as I did not find `SET AUTOCOMMIT` statements before and after the insert statement.

So, I assume that the transactions are not configured well.

What would be the problem in my settings ?

Comment: Do you assume that the 3d method will roll back the actions of first two methods?

Comment: what's your hibernate configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that I annotated the service with the wrong transaction manager and this what leads to the previous strange behavior

The service (I was using) was annotated with

@transactional(value='transaction_manger_1')

This transaction manager is configured to work with the read_only DB while the injected DAO was using the correct session factory which works with the read/write DB.

So I have changed the transaction manager to the correct one and every thing goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

You configured the app so that it opens a new transaction for every call to the service (which is the class that is transactional ). You need to either start the transaction in the controller or wrap your calls in another method on service level.